# How to add two button in grid.mvc control in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid.mvc

I want to add two button control in one column. currently i can able to add Download button on one column . but i want to add delete button beside to download button in same columns.
    please suggest on the same.
I have given code..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "Download", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>  
{
    columns.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(0)
       .RenderValueAs(o => @<input id="id" name="IsChecked" value= @o.id , type="checkbox"/>);

    columns.Add(data => data.FileName).Titled("File Name").SetWidth(50);
    columns.Add(data => data.DisplayedDate).Titled("Uploaded Date").SetWidth(40);
    columns.Add(data => data.User_Name).Titled("User Name").SetWidth(50);

    columns.Add()
    .Encoded(false)
    .Sanitized(false)
    .SetWidth(80)
    .RenderValueAs(data => @<button type="submit" value ="">Download</button>);
}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).Filterable(true)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the overload for `RenderValueAs` accepts `IHtmlString`.

So you can do:

```
.RenderValueAs(data => new HtmlString
                       (
                         "<button type='submit' value=''>Download</button> 
                          <button type='button' value=''>Upload</button>"
                       )
               );
```

Or you can do:

```
.RenderValueAs(data => "<button type='submit' value=''>Download</button> 
                        <button type='button' value=''>Upload</button>"
                );
```

If you need more control, there is a [Custom Layout](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Render%20button%2C%20checkbox%20etc%20in%20the%20grid%20cell) rendering feature that you can use.

Comment: Hi, this is what I was looking for, can you add, how how to POST action an approve or reject button with the values, rowId, and model

Comment: This works very well, but don't forget to put ".Encoded(false)" before RenderValueAs part.

Answer (score 3):

```
columns.Add(c => c.PrecioVenta).Titled("Precio de Venta").Filterable(true);
columns.Add(c => c.Cantidad).Titled("Cantidad").Filterable(true);
columns.Add()
.Encoded(false)
.Sanitized(false)
.SetWidth(30)
.RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = o.IdProducto }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }));
columns.Add()
.Encoded(false)
.Sanitized(false)
.SetWidth(30)
.RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Details", new { id = o.IdProducto }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" }));
```