# How to render 2 controls inside Grid.Mvc column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, grid.mvc

I need to render a label and a text input at each row in a Grid.Mvc control.
Each row can have a diferente label and control according to row type.

I can render html controls using the htmlHelper, but how can i create an div control with a laber and a text input?

Here is were i go so far:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.WFMaster.Activities).Columns(columns =>
{     
   columns.Add().Titled("Parameter").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(a =>
   {           
      if ...
         //Stuck here. I can't create an div and add controls to it.
          return Html.TextBox("value");        
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that output, you can make use of overload of RenderValueAs that accepts Ihtmlstring. Here is the example.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.WFMaster.Activities).Columns(columns =>
{     
   columns.Add().Titled("Parameter").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(a =>
  new HtmlString
                       (
                         <div>
                         <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                         <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                         </div>
                       )
);


});
```

Sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33493299/3397630